# Cholesky factorization of $A M A^T$ for $M$ PSD with known Cholesky factorization.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, cholesky-decomposition

In the context of my research, I am trying to efficiently compute/store a PSD matrix and the cholesky factorization might help.

Let $M\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $A\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ be such that $M$ has Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$ (or alternatively $M=LDL^T$ with $L$ lower triangular and diagonal equal to $1$ if simpler). The matrix $N=AMA^T$ is PSD and I want to compute its Cholesky decomposition (or $LDL^T$ decomposition). I am wondering if there is a fast way of doing this using the knowledge of $L$ and $A$ that doesn't require to decompose $ALL^TA^T$.

Any reference on the subject or intuition is most welcome, I don't have any solid lead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ s.p.d. and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and define $N = AMA^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$. Assume we have $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with $M = L L ^T$.
Then
$$
N = AMA^T = ALL^TA^T = (AL)(AL)^T = K K ^T,
$$
and we have found a <s>the Cholesky</s> factorization$N = K K^T$ with $K = AL$.

- Computing $AL$ needs $O(mn^2)$ operations.
- Computing the Cholesky factorization of $N$ directly needs $O(m^3)$ operations.

For $n\ll m$ there is a benefit in reusing the old factorization.

---

(We assume $m \le n$ in the following.)

The matrix $K$ is not a square matrix and not lower triangular so we have not computed a Cholesky factorization. However, there is a way to compute a cholesky factorization from $K$.

Compute a LQ decomposition of $K \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$:
$$
K = \overline{L} Q,
$$
with $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ orthogonal and $\overline{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ lower triangular. The matrix $\overline{L}$ has the form
$$
\overline{L} = \left(\begin{array} 1 \tilde{L} & \mathbf{0} \end{array}\right),
$$
with $\tilde{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ lower triangular and $ \mathbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times (n -m)}$ the zero matrix.

Then, we get
$$
N = KK^T = LQQ^TL^T = LL^T = \tilde{L} \tilde{L}^T,
$$
which is a Cholesky factorization.

- Computing a LQ decomposition of $K$ needs $O(n m^2)$ operations.

Comment: Isn't $K$ of shape $m\times n$ instead of the desired $m\times m$ ? Also it isn't lower triangular right ?

Comment: You are right, sorry for the misconception. In the context you are interested in, do you have $n \le m$ or $n \ge m$ or can both cases happen?

Comment: @AverageJow It will be typical that $m\leq n$.

Comment: I edited my answer and included a way to compute a Cholesky factorization from $K$, maybe this helps.

Comment: #AverageJoe Nice, thank you. However I was expecting to beat the $O(nm^2+n^2m)$ cost of multiplying directly $AMA^T$ and then taking the Cholesky factorization. Maybe there is a way to compute the $LQ$ decomposition of $AL$ without multiplying $A$ and $L$, this might result in an improvement from $O(mn^2)$ to $O(m^2n)$ in the case $m\leq n$.